# improper integrals in q-calculus

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, improper-integrals, q-series, quantum-calculus

In quantum calculus is this equality possible for improper integrals?

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^xf(t)d_qt=\int_0^\infty f(x)d_qx$

Comment: That's the definition of $\int_0^\infty$ in most contexts.

Comment: i confuse to take limit because quantum calculus is called calculus without limits